# In this example, how columnar database is faster compared to RDBMS

Tags: database, vertica

In this example, how is a `columnar` database like `Vertica` better than an `rdbms`w.r.t speed?

I am assuming that `Symbol` and `date` are `primary key` w.r.t `rdbms`

[image]

From the example I am following, the projection looks like the following but I can't figure out why the no. of reads is less

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tickstore only has the three columns you are using in your example (and practically only then), the row-oriented DBMS might be faster - especially if you have `symbol` and `date` indexed.

But in any other case: each column in a columnar database (and Vertica was the first widely known one) boils down to a file by itself. So , in the case of 103 columns in the table, the row-oriented DBMS reads 100 columns too many from disk, while Vertica reads only 3; the row-oriented DBMS needs to navigate through the complete read row to find the starts of each column needed in the query; and Vertica can rely on the fact that each column-file contains exactly one data type, and can optimise both reading and writing processes to take advantage of that knowledge.

Plus there are encoding algorithms for column-oriented data that would blow up the space of this answer to go into detail for here.

To sum it up: the only thing a column oriented database does not like is a `SELECT *` of a 100-plus column table.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that ` each column in a columnar database is a file` or ` each projection in a columnar database is a file`? Is it that in RDBMS, the row is read and then 103 columns are read because the entire row is fetched in a RDBMS. But in columnar DBs, the correct row will ideally have only 3 columns (the projection)?

Comment: Each column in Vertica (which is a columnar RDBMS) is usually a file by itself. The projection groups those files together. When you query the table, the result rows are built together thanks to additional stored information that allows to navigate to the right value in the next column from a found value in a column you already have. That's why a `SELECT *` is more expensive in a columnar RDBMS than in a row oriented RDBMS.